# Check if an HTML file is accessed directly or has been redirected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, react-fullstack

I have two HTML files: one.html and two.html

File *one.html refers to file *one.js* and file *two.html* refers file *two.js*.

Now, file *one.js* simply redirects to file *two.html* using *windows.location* of jQuery.

Is there a way to check within file *two.js* if file *two.html* was redirected from file *one.js* or it (file *two.html*) was accessed directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.referrer
```

gives you the last page that the user has visited. You can use it to determine where the user came from.

Comment: ...most of the time.     _The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, by using a bookmark). Because this property returns only a string, it doesn't give you document object model (DOM) access to the referring page._